# Iterating over PHP array with Laravel Blade, and then adding in HTML for columns

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have an array with 38 records.

After iterating over the first 10 I want it to start on a new column.

This is very simple and an example is below, however, I need to add in HTML which makes it difficult:

```
@for($i = 0; $i < count($records); $i++)
    @if($i % 10 == 0)
        //start new column
    @endif

    <li><a href="#">{{ $records[$i]['name'] }}</a></li>
@endfor
```

What the HTML looks like **without** looping and what it should look like after looping properly:

```
<li class="col-sm-3">
    <li class="dropdown-header">
        Record Set
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Record Name</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Record Name</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Record Name</a></li>
</li>
```

Problem is, after 10 records I need it to break out of `col-sm-3` and start a new `col-sm-3` without the `dropdown-header` but with each iteration's record name.

How can this be done?  Please ask questions if clarification is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's an array then you may use [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php#refsect1-function.array-chunk-examples):

```
@foreach(array_chunk($records, 10) as $ten_arrays)
    <li class="col-sm-3">
        @foreach($ten_arrays as $record)
           {{ $record['field_name'] }}
        @endforeach
    </li>
@endforeach
```

This will output `li`s like this:

```
<li class="col-sm-3">
    <!-- Ten Items -->
</li>

<li class="col-sm-3">
    <!-- Ten Items -->
</li>
```

Comment: I'm getting undefined index for my keys in the array.

Comment: What you have in the `array`, what fields ?